# AudioRecord record audio quality is very distorted when played back using AudioTrack

Tags: java, android

Hey I am attempting the following: Record audio on one mobile device (e.g Android Smartphone) send the record audio to N mobile devices using multicast and playback the recorded audio. I can record, transmit, and playback the audio. However the playback audio is very distorted and I cannot figure out if it is the `AudioRecord` or the `AudioTrack` which is configured wrong.

My recorder is configured like this:

```
    public static int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
    ...
    mRecorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
            .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            .setAudioFormat(
                    new AudioFormat.Builder()
                            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                            .setSampleRate(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE)
                            .setChannelIndexMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT)
                            .build())
            .setBufferSizeInBytes(AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 4)
            .build();
```

And my track is configured like this:

```
    mTrack = new AudioTrack.Builder().setAudioAttributes(
            new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build())
            .setAudioFormat(
                    new AudioFormat.Builder()
                            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                            .setSampleRate(44100)
                            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO).build())
            .setBufferSizeInBytes(AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT))
            .build();
```

I have tried different buffer sizes, different Usage and Content types, but  still get the same distorted result.

I hope someone can help with this

Comment: How do you transfer your file?

Comment: What file? It is record straight from microphone. I use a proprietary protocol called Score. where I passe the byte array read from the recorder